# How to handle a range within a data field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a set of data with ranges of numbers that are saved to the field itself. So for example, in the age column there are entries like "60-64", "65+" and in the income field "30\,000-40\,000". Is there a way to query these fields and treat them as number ranges? So a query for 52500 would match the "50\,000-60\,000" income range?

Preprocessing the input is my current top idea, where I just map the user input to all possible values for these fields before I query the database. But I was wondering if there is a better way.

Assume that I cannot modify the database or create a new database at all.

Comment: Is there an actual `\\` in the income data values?

Comment: What I posted is directly copy/pasted from the data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way with SQLite that I know off, and you certainly would be better off to restructure all your `range` columns into two columns each, `range_start` and `range_end`.

If your ranges are fixed ranges, you can get the minimum / maximum from a separate table:

```
create table age_ranges (
    name varchar(16) unique not null
  , range_start integer unique not null
  , range_end   integer unique not null
);
insert into age_ranges (name, range_start,range_end) values ('60-64',60,64);
insert into age_ranges (name, range_start,range_end) values ('65+',65,999);

create table participant (
    name varchar(16) unique not null
  , age integer not null
  , income integer not null
);
insert into participant (name, age, income) values ('Joe Blow', 65, 900);
insert into participant (name, age, income) values  ('Jane Doe' , 61 , 1900)
;

create table question (
    question varchar(64) not null
  , relevant_age varchar(32) not null
);
insert into question (question,relevant_age) values('What is your favourite non-beige color?', '65+');
insert into question (question,relevant_age) values('What is your favourite car?', '60-64');
;
select
    p.name,
    q.question,
    q.relevant_age
from participant p
    join age_ranges r on (r.range_start <= p.age and p.age <= r.range_end)
    join question q on q.relevant_age = r.name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ab08/2)

Alternatively, you can also try to parse the range start and range end out by using string functions such as `LEFT()` etc., but the performance will likely bad.